# String-Comparison in java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to compare a value from a cell in a JTable and a value returned from an SQL ResultSet, but it always return FALSE even if I know they are equal.

Their content equals "1"
I also checked for the length of each string which is 1.

```
    boolean test = (myJTable.getValueAt(0, 0).toString() == rs.getString("ID"))
    //test equals to false.
```

What makes them different??

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: Use `String#equals()`, that will check if the Strings have the same data. Using `==` compares references.

Comment: If this question is so redundant, how come I have never cross it in any tutorial of java about operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare String using `==`, use `equals()` method.

Try this:

```
boolean test = (myJTable.getValueAt(0, 0).toString().equals(rs.getString("ID")));
```

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)